# How to use abbrev with different configuration for each mode?

Tags: abbrev

How can abbrev-mode be enabled per mode (so enable for `org-mode` and `python-mode` for example, but not other modes).
And each mode use its own set of abbreviations?

Comment: Are you looking for `M-x define-mode-abbrev`? You can enable any minor mode (abbrev being one such mode) by adding it to a hook that that mode executes when it starts, see example: https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AbbrevMode#toc4 . More extended info on local / global abbrevs: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Defining-Abbrevs.html#Defining-Abbrevs

Comment: I've seen the docs for using abbrev with mode hooks, what I dont know is how to couple this with a different abbrev file for each mode.

Comment: Use `add-mode-abbrev` instead of `add-global-abbrev`? [(emacs) Defining Abbrevs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Defining-Abbrevs.html)